# Using navigation properties inside a grouped select statement

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to use a column from a navigation property to do a calculation inside a grouped select statment like so:

```cs
var result = await (
    from items in Items.Include(e=>e.ItemInfo)
    where items.status == "INV"                                           
    group rolls by items.origin into grp                 
    select new
    {
        origin = grp.Key.origin,
        total = (grp.Sum(e => e.count * (e.ItemInfo.price + e.ItemInfo.upcharge))),
    }).ToListAsync();
```

However, it can't translate this saying

```
The LINQ expression '(EntityShaperExpression: 
    EntityType: itemTable
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
    IsNullable: False
).count * (EntityShaperExpression: 
    EntityType: itemTable
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
    IsNullable: False
).ItemInfo.price' could not be translated.
```

I've also tried using:

```cs
var result= Item.Include(e=>e.ItemInfo)
    .Where(e => e.status == "INV")
    .GroupBy(e => e.origin)
    .Select(g => new {origin = g.Key.origin,
                      total = (g.Sum(e=> e.count * (e.ItemInfo.price+e.ItemInfo.upcharge)))});
```

This seems like it should be a simple query. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put navigation property into projection:

```cs
var query = 
    from items in ItemDatabase
    where items.status == "INV"                                           
    group new { items, items.ItemInfo } by items.origin into grp                 
    select new
    {
        origin = grp.Key,
        total = grp.Sum(e => e.items.count * (e.ItemInfo.price + e.ItemInfo.upcharge)),
    };
```

Comment: No error any more since the answer was edited right after I posted my comment about syntax. It's all good now, thanks. I edited the code without changing functionality so I was able to re-upvote it.